# What is the complete question that Smith is asking here?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

In *L.A Confidential* (1997), Smith saw Edmund's top-ranking test results among 23 candidates. Wondering about
Edmund's next move, Smith suggested options. Edmund chose the Detective Bureau,
despite Smith's observation that he hesitates to confront weaknesses. Edmund
disagreed, prompting Smith to repeat his questions:

> Smith: Would you beat a confession out of a suspect you knew to be
> guilty?
>
> Edmund: No.
>
> Smith: **Would you shoot a hardened criminal in the back  in order to
> offset the chance that some lawyer--?**
>
> Edmund: No.

What is the complete question that Smith is asking here?

Comment: Okay. I'd ask everyone to calm down and take a break. This conversation is not going anywhere. Therefore I am removing it. Comment is not a place for this. Use [chat] instead if you really want to continue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not mentioned in any version or transcript I've checked so far:

1. [Script - 5/3/1996](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/l-a-confidential-1997.pdf)
2. [Script early draft](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/ellay-confidential_early.html)
3. [Full transcript](https://subslikescript.com/movie/LA_Confidential-119488)

What you can *guess* is something like:

> Would you shoot a hardened criminal in the back in order to offset the chance that some lawyer *can get him off the hook*?

Comment: The general question Smith is posing is whether Exley is prepared to break the rules–if necessarily severely–in order to achieve justice (which appears to be fairly standard practice in the detective bureau). The context is clear.